# How to write an express route middleware that will only catch actions?

Tags: node.js, express, connect

I'm using the following middleware :

```
  app.use(function(req,res,next){
     console.log(req.url)
     next()
  });
```

but it catches every request, including images/css/js etc...

If I just want to catch the actions, what should I do?

Comment: Take a look at [`express.logger`](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/logger.html).

Comment: Just to add to what @elmigranto said:`app.use(express.logger('dev'));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could put your "static handler" middleware before this one, if the request matches the static middleware route, it should not reach your middleware at all.

So try:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(function(req,res,next){
  console.log(req.url)
  next()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

detail explanation about express and connect middleware Check this url
http://www.hacksparrow.com/how-to-write-midddleware-for-connect-express-js.html